# Assign value in for loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the actual month from a loop. When I step through it in developer tools and `month[i]` == 4 it doesn't assign `actualMonth` to `checkMonth`

Do I have to assign `getMonth` to `month[]` and then try and query the value?

```
var showCurrentMonth = function() {
    var getMonth = new Date().getMonth();

    var month = ["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"];

    var actualMonth = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
        var checkMonth = month[i];
        console.log(month[i]);
        if (getMonth == month[i]) {
            actualMonth = checkMonth;
        }
    }
    console.log(actualMonth);
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', showCurrentMonth, false);
```

Comment: getMonth() returns an integer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too simple?

```js
var showCurrentMonth = function() {
    var getMonth = new Date().getMonth();

    var month = ["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"];

    var actualMonth = month[getMonth];
    
    console.log(actualMonth);
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', showCurrentMonth, false);
```

Comment: just what I wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are comparing an integer and string:

```
var getMonth = new Date().getMonth(); // This return number from 0 to 11
```

The code `Date().getMonth()` returns an integer, and your `month` list has strings on it

Your code should be:

```
var showCurrentMonth = function() {
    var getMonth = new Date().getMonth();

    var month = ["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"];

    var actualMonth = month[getMonth];
    console.log(actualMonth);
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', showCurrentMonth, false);
```

To get the actual month you only need to access the month list with **getMonth** as index

Comment: actually getMonth() returns value between 0 and 11: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Comment: Yup, you're right I was changing the answer because the boucle is not needed there, he only needs to access the month list with the getMonth as index

Answer (score 2):

Change your if to `if (month[getMonth] == month[i]) {`

Do it like this :

```
 var showCurrentMonth = function() {
    var getMonth = new Date().getMonth();

    var month = ["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"];

    var actualMonth = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
        var checkMonth = month[i];
        console.log(month[i]);
        if (month[getMonth] == month[i]) {  //Compare get month like this
            actualMonth = checkMonth;
        }
    }
    console.log(actualMonth);
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', showCurrentMonth, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

slightly Modification required

```
var showCurrentMonth = function() {
        var getMonth = new Date().getMonth();
        console.log(getMonth);
        var month = ["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"];

        var actualMonth = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
            var checkMonth = month[i];

            if (getMonth == i) {
                actualMonth = checkMonth;
            }
        }
        console.log(actualMonth);
    };
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', showCurrentMonth, false);
```

Comment: The boucle is not needed, the only need there is to access the month list with the **getMonth** value as index, no need to enter in a boucle of month length